# Load event jQuery, can i append it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, load

I want load a html part with ajax in the page. I have a html page. With ajax, i want load from a other page a part html.

I make this code:

```
$.get(/vision.html/, function(data){
    $(data).find(".container-helper").appendTo(".wrapper");
});
```

From the vision.html page. I want load the container-helper div. And i want append that html to the .wrapper div in the page. But this code is not working.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do $(".wrapper").html(data.find(".container-helper").html()) ?

Comment: Maybe you just need to use `"` around url `$.get("vision.html", ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `filter` rather than `find`. Like so:

`$(data).filter('.container-helper').appendTo('.wrapper')`

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your code with following:

```
$.get("vision.html", function(data){
        $response = $(data);
        $response.filter('.container-helper').appendTo('.wrapper');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

vision.html should only return the .container-helper content.

```
<div class="container-helper">some content</div>


$.get('vision.html', function(data){
    $(data).appendTo('.wrapper');
});
```